# How to integrate a function of derivatives.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have the equation
$$\frac{\text{d}^2x}{\text{d}t^2}\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t}+\frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t}=0$$
and I'm unsure how to integrate it with respect to $\text{d}t$. If I split it up and integrate each part I understand that $\int\frac{\text{d}V}{\text{d}t}\text{d}t=V(x)$, and $\int0\,\text{d}t=constant$, but I'm struggling with the first term. I have the result that
$$\int\ddot{x}\dot{x}\,\text{d}t=\frac{1}{2}\dot{x}^2$$
but I don't understand how this is done? I've seen a couple of other answers on this site with essentially the same integral but I just don't get it, I've written it out over and over and manipulated it all sorts of ways but the penny just isn't dropping. Could someone spell it out for me as simply as possible? I'm not sure if it's the Leibniz notation that I'm getting lost in and thinking of them too much like fractions rather than operators, or if it turns out I just don't get the chain rule and implicit differentiation after all.

Comment: It's just chain rule. If you let $u=\dot{x}$ then $du=\ddot{x}dt$

Answer (score 1):

Make the substitution $y = \frac12\dot{x}^2.$ Then your equation has the form:

$$\dot{y} + \dot{V} = 0.$$

Integrate with respect to $t$ to get

$y + V = C,$ so

$y = (C-V),$ so

$\dot{x} = 2 \sqrt{C- V}.$

So $x = \int 2 \sqrt{C-V} dt.$

Answer (score 1):

The formula you are interested in can be written as:

$$ \int \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)}{\mathrm{d}t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}t $$

(writing the second derivative this way makes algebraic manipulation make a lot more sense)

We can cancel a $\mathrm{d}t$ as follows:

$$ \int \mathrm{d}\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

So, the integrand is just $u\,\mathrm{d}u$, so its integral will be $\frac{u^2}{2}$.

Comment: By the way, as a bit of self-promotion, for more ways of dealing with algebraically manipulable forms of the second derivative, see my paper "Extending the Algebraic Manipulability of Differentials."